# Conectando pentaho com MySQL

Tags: mysql

Como corrigir o erro de conexão do banco de dados MySql com Pentaho

> Error connecting to database [Escola]
>   :org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:  Error
>   occurred while trying to connect to the database
>
> Driver class 'org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver' could not be found, make sure
>   the 'MySQL' driver (jar file) is installed. org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
>
> org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:  Error occurred
>   while trying to connect to the database
>
> Driver class 'org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver' could not be found, make sure
>   the 'MySQL' driver (jar file) is installed. org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
>
> at
>   org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:472)
>     at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:370)
>     at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:341)
>     at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:331)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:80)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnection(DatabaseMeta.java:2783)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.ui.database.event.DataHandler.testDatabaseConnection(DataHandler.java:597)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:313)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:157)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:141)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton.access$500(SwtButton.java:43)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton$4.widgetSelected(SwtButton.java:137)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:820)     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:796)     at
>   org.pentaho.di.ui.xul.KettleDialog.show(KettleDialog.java:80)     at
>   org.pentaho.di.ui.xul.KettleDialog.show(KettleDialog.java:47)     at
>   org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.XulDatabaseDialog.open(XulDatabaseDialog.java:116)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.DatabaseDialog.open(DatabaseDialog.java:60)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonDBDelegate.newConnection(SpoonDBDelegate.java:485)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonDBDelegate.newConnection(SpoonDBDelegate.java:472)
>     at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.newConnection(Spoon.java:8788)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:313)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:157)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:141)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.ui.xul.jface.tags.JfaceMenuitem.access$100(JfaceMenuitem.java:43)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.ui.xul.jface.tags.JfaceMenuitem$1.run(JfaceMenuitem.java:106)
>     at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)    at
>   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:545)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:490)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:402)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1366)    at
>   org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:8022)     at
>   org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9277)  at
>   org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:692)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92) Caused
>   by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:  Driver
>   class 'org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver' could not be found, make sure the
>   'MySQL' driver (jar file) is installed. org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
>
> at
>   org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:515)
>     at
>   org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:456)
>     ... 57 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:490)
>     ... 58 more

Answer (score 1):

Copie o arquivo `mysql-connector-java-5.1.42-bin.jar` para a pasta `pdi-ce-8.1.0.0-365\data-integration\lib` e reinicie a ide do PDI